# Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

which is the best  PHP Class for Amazon web services?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on board! It's [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)